# Loading from a Struct data type and trouble passing that data to another function

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have asked my classmates and they have no clue why this is. The Program is supposed to be a banking program. I initially noticed problems specifically in my function `findCustomer`. What it is supposed to do is to take in a certain piece of the structure 'account' find if the account number matches up to the input you put in, and then declare it a match.

```
int findCustomer(account arr[], int customers)
{
    int index;

    cout << "Account Number?: ";
    cin >> index;

    for (int i = 0; i <= customers + 1; i++)
        if (arr[i].acctNum == index)
        {
            cout << "You dun good!"; //I put this here to try to figure out what the problem was when it was passing in.
            return i;
            break;
        }
        else if (arr[i].acctNum != index)
        {
            cout << "Account Number (" << index << ") Does Not exist!" << endl;
            system("Pause");
            system("CLS");
            return -1;
        }
```

After that it is supposed to pass into a deposit/withdrawal function (they both act the same with minor differences).

```
void deposit(account arr[], int customers)
{
    char type;
    float money;
    int i;
    i = findCustomer(arr, customers);
    cout << i << "At this point" << endl;    
    if (i = -1)
    {
        cout << "You dun goofed!"; //again put here as a trigger
        // what normally goes here is a return; statement to break the function
    }


    type = submenu();

    cout << "How much would you like to deposit?: ";
    cin >> money;

    cout << "Number \t Name \t Balance" << endl;
    cout << "=========================================" << endl;
    if (type = 's')
    {    arr[i].sBal += money;
        cout << arr[i].acctNum << "\t" << arr[i].name << "\t" << arr[i].sBal;
    }
    else if (type = 'c')
    {    arr[i].cBal += money;
        cout << arr[i].acctNum << "\t" << arr[i].name << "\t" << arr[i].cBal;
    }
}
```

The output I am getting suggests that there is a change from 0 to -1 right in the middle of the function without any declaration to do so (leaving me with a giant wth over my head) which of course dorks the entire function. I also seem to be having problems reading in certain account numbers that have been said to have been loaded in previous functions. Any and all help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think you mean `i <= customers ***-*** 1` (or `i < customers`). You're going out of bounds  if `customers` is the length of the array. You might as well use `std::array` or `std::vector` if you can, too.

Comment: Your `findCustomer` function also only loops once because both paths return a value.

Comment: findCustomer is broken... you should only let the first IF in the FOR then close the loop and in the end return -1 because if it reaches that point, the customer was never found in the loop